# Integral curves of the gradient

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function defined on a riemannian manifold. Assume that $| \mathrm{grad}f | = 1$ over all $M$. Show that the integral curves of $\mathrm{grad}f$ are geodesics.

Comment: If an integral curve was not a geodesic the gradient vector would have trouble being tangent to the integral curve, no?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since this seems to be homework, here is just an outline of the proof.

1. Show that the map $X\rightarrow \nabla_X \nabla f$ is self adjoint, that is, that $g(\nabla_X \nabla f, Y) = g(\nabla_Y \nabla f, X)$ for any vector fields $X$ and $Y$.  You'll need to use the fact that $\nabla f$ is a gradient field, but you won't need the fact that it has norm 1.
2. Show that $g(\nabla_{\nabla f} \nabla f, X) = 0$ for all $X$ by using 1. to write it as $g(\nabla_X \nabla f, \nabla f)$ and expanding.  Here, you'll need to use the fact that $\nabla f$ has norm 1.  Once you show this, conclude that $\nabla_{\nabla f} \nabla f = 0$, i.e., that the integral curves are geodesics.

Assuming I remember, or that you send a comment, I can update this in a few days with full solutions to either 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks! I've alredy done the calculations and it works wonders :). I have one question though: It seems to me that this works if we let that $|\mathrm{grad}(f)|$ is constant.

Comment: Right, $|\nabla f|$ constant is all we need.  Different magnitudes of $|\nabla f|$ just correspond to different scalings of $f$.

Comment: Dear Jason: this is great. It is easy to think about the second step, but could you explain a bit how one can think of the first step? It seems to be coming from nowhere to me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking 6 years ago.  Probably I had already seen that outline before.  A guess is that Petersen's Riemannian geoemtry text book has it, either worked out or as an exercise.  But, as you said, step 2 is relatively clear (how do you show a vector is 0?  Inner product it with everything!), and then step 1 follows as something necessary for step 2 to work.  So, perhaps, attempting Step 1 is somewhat natural.

Comment: $$0=d^2f(X,Y)=X(df(Y))-Y(df(X))-df([X,Y])=X\langle\nabla f, Y\rangle - Y\langle\nabla f, X\rangle - \langle\nabla f, [X,Y]\rangle =$$ $$ \left< \nabla_X \nabla f, Y \right> + \left< \nabla f, \nabla_X Y \right> - \left< \nabla_Y \nabla f, X \right> - \left< \nabla f, \nabla_Y X \right> - \left< \nabla f, [X,Y] \right> = $$ $$\left< \nabla_X \nabla f, Y \right> - \left< \nabla_Y \nabla f, X \right> + \left<\nabla f, \nabla_X Y  - \nabla_Y X - [X,Y]\right> = \left< \nabla_X \nabla f, Y \right> - \left< \nabla_Y \nabla f, X \right> $$

Comment: @JasonDeVito-onhiatus: I just saw your answer, and when you wrote "You'll need to use the fact that $\nabla f$ is a gradient field", did you really mean that $Hess(f)$ is symmetric w.r.t. $(X,Y),$ and thus the first step follows?

Answer (score 5):

An intuitive method of approaching this is as follows.
If $t\mapsto x(t)$ is an integral curve then $\vert f(x(t_1))-f(x(t_0))\vert=\vert t_1-t_0\vert$. However, any other curve $t\mapsto y(t)$ joining points $y(s_0)=x(t_0)$ and $y(s_1)=x(t_1)$ satisfies $\vert f(y(s_1))-f(y(s_0))\vert\le\vert s_1-s_0\vert$ when parameterized by arc length. So $x$ is the shortest curve between the points.

Comment: Why does it have to happen that $|f(x(t1))−f(x(t0))|=|t1−t1|$ ?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now :) (there's a little typo it shoud be $|t1−t0|$)

Comment: Why would $\vert f(x(t_1))-f(x(t_0))\vert=\vert t_1-t_0\vert$ or $\vert f(y(t_1))-f(y(t_0))\vert\leq\vert t_1-t_0\vert$ for that matter be true?? The function $f:M \to \mathbb R$ is an arbitrary differentiable function, so the function which maps everything to zero is also allowed. This would however mean that $0 = \vert t_1-t_0 \vert $ which is not correct unless $t_1=t_0$.

Comment: @gonenc: We are assuming that $\lvert{\rm grad}f\rvert=1$.

Comment: Yeah right.. but my question still stands. Why do we have $\vert f(x(t_1))-f(x(t_0))\vert=\vert t_1-t_0\vert$ or $\vert f(y(t_1))-f(y(t_0))\vert\leq\vert t_1-t_0\vert$?

Comment: @GonencMogol Rather late to the party but: $df(x(t))/dt = $ derivative of $f$ in the direction of $gamma'(t) = \langle grad(f),dx/dt\rangle = ||grad(f)||^2 = 1$ by our assumption. Integrating both sides with respect to $t$ we get what we want.

Comment: @GonencMogol As for the second part, if we parametrize by arc length, then $||y'(s)|| = 1$ and as in the first part, $f(s_2) - f(s_1)$ = \integral_{s} df(y(s))/ds ds = \integral_s \langle grad(f) , y'(s) \rangle ds . Now, this inner product is between two vectors of length one and therefore has magnitude $\leq 1$ as required.

Answer (score 4):

Another strategy: define coordinates $(x^1, \ldots, x^{n-1}, y)$ at points $p \in M$ so that $(x^1, \ldots, x^{n-1})$ are local slice coordinates for the level sets $\{q \in M : f(q) = f(p)\}$, and $y \in \mathbb R$ satisfies $f(\gamma_p(y)) = f(q)$, where $\gamma_p$ is the integral curve of $\mathrm{grad} f$ starting at $p$. In these coordinates, $\mathrm{grad} f = \partial_y$, and $g(\partial_{i}, \partial_y) \equiv 0$, where $\partial_i := \partial_{x^i}$. Furthermore, $g(\partial_y, \partial_y) = |\mathrm{grad}f|^2 \equiv 1$. We'll prove $D_t \dot\gamma(t) \equiv 0$ in these coordinates for every integral curve $\gamma$ of $\mathrm{grad}f$.

By symmetry of the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ and commutativity of coordinate vector fields, $\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_y = \nabla_{\partial_y} \partial_i$. So, since $\nabla$ is compatible with the Riemannian metric, for $i = 1, \ldots, n-1$, 
\begin{align*}
\left\langle D_t \dot\gamma(t), \partial_i\right\rangle &= \frac d{dt} \left\langle \dot\gamma(t), \partial_i\right\rangle - \left\langle \dot\gamma(t), D_t \partial_i \right\rangle = \frac{d}{dt} \langle \partial_y, \partial_i \rangle - \left\langle \partial_y, \nabla_{\partial_y} \partial_i \right\rangle = -\left\langle \partial_y, \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_y \right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_y, \partial_y \right\rangle - \partial_i \left\langle \partial_n, \partial_n \right\rangle = \left\langle \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_y, \partial_y \right\rangle = -\left\langle D_t \dot\gamma(t), \partial_i\right\rangle.
\end{align*}
So $\left\langle D_t \dot\gamma(t), \partial_i\right\rangle = 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n-1$. Furthermore, 
$$
\left\langle D_t \dot\gamma(t), \partial_y\right\rangle = \left\langle D_t \partial_y, \partial_y\right\rangle=\frac d{dt} \left\langle \partial_y, \partial_y \right\rangle - \left\langle \partial_y, D_t \partial_y \right\rangle = - \left\langle \partial_y, D_t \partial_y \right\rangle.
$$
So, $\left\langle D_t \dot\gamma(t), \partial_y\right\rangle = 0$, whence $\left\langle D_t \dot\gamma(t), X\right\rangle \equiv 0$ for every vector field $X$ over $M$. So $D_t \dot\gamma(t) \equiv 0$, so $\gamma(t)$ is geodesic.